# iOS 7 iPhone how can I close my running applications?

Tags: iphone

I have an iPhone 4 and just updated the software to i OS 7. Before I updated the software I had been able to close my running apps to keep from running down the battery. I can't figure out now how to close them. Is there a way or do theft close themselves or what?

Comment: The answers already received show the steps you need to take, but it's worth understanding that chances are unless the app was actively streaming music, or accessing GPS etc, then it would most likely have been in a "fast app switching" state, whereby it wasn't actually running at all, nor using up battery.  Only certain tasks were allowed to run in the background, and the "multitasking" list was more of a "recent apps" list in reality, most often when your think you were "closing" an app, you were just removing it from your list.

Answer (score 1):

Double clic on the home button then slide the apps to the top to quit them.

Comment: But remember: what you see there is a "recently used" list, not a "now running" list.

Answer (score 0):

You can kill running applications by swiping them upwards after double tapping the Home button.

You can also disable background app refresh (a new iOS 7 feature) by disabling it under: Settings > General > Background App Refresh.

Applications typically stay running as long as the OS has enough resources for it, until reboot, or until you manually kill them. Some iOS applications can run in the background while actively using your phone's CPU (music players are a good example). iOS may kill background applications to give a foreground application more resources.

Answer (score 0):

Same way as before. But iOS does a great job of managing running resources for you, so if you have a decrease of battery life, it could be that the OS is to much for your phone to handle, depending on which iPhone it is of course. "Multi-Tasking" in iOS is really just recently used applications (which is where you double click home and swipe up) and the background app refresh works pretty well.

Ultimately though, iPhones are meant to be self-sufficient, even in the matters of running processes. I understand you thinking that apps running in the background are the cause in the decrease of battery life, but maybe it could be iOS 7. After updating my 4S, My already-bad battery life decreased even more, no matter what I did. So I guess you either have to get a new phone or suffer, because the new design of iOS 7 is just to much for older phones.